# having issue with python decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I was trying to learn more about Python decorators using excellent tutorial at https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/.

I tried to deviate from the script and am running into some issues.  The code is below.  Basically, when I run the script below, the first function call to
time_print_function() executes as expected.

But I get an error in the next function call  my_decorator(print(datetime.datetime.now()))()

I expected that this will produce output same as time_print_function()

***Code is***

```
def my_decorator(some_function):
  def wrapper(*args):
      print "Something is happening before some_function() is called."


  if args:
    some_function(args)
  else:
    some_function()
  print "Something is happening after some_function() is called."


return wrapper

@my_decorator
def time_print_function():
  print(datetime.datetime.now())
time_print_function()
my_decorator(print(datetime.datetime.now()))()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this expression:

```
my_decorator(print(datetime.datetime.now()))()
```

Already calls the print function before passing it as a parameter to
the `my_decorator`  call. The `my_decorator` receives the return value
of `print` which is None and tries to call it, yielding an error
(None is obviously not callable).

The argument to a decorator should be a function - you can
create one inline using lambda, for example in:

```
my_decorator(lambda: print(datetime.datetime.now()) )()
```

Comment: Thanks.  Still seeing an error. Do I need to import something before I can use lambda. I tried import os.                                                                      File "decorator_examples.py", line 53
  
 my_decorator(lambda: print(datetime.datetime.now()) )()
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: Not for lambda, but for using "print" as a function you have to either be using Python3.x or do `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.x